# ChromeOS: kill a hung ssh session

Tags: ssh, google-chrome-os, cr-48, chromebook

I have a hung crosh terminal. I was in a ssh session and the wireless connection dropped. The screen froze. Normally, I open an other one, ssh into the remote machine again, and kill the sshd, and that clears it. However, the sshd on the remote machine closed itself overnight and now the crosh terminal is hung, thinking it's still connected.

What's the best way to kill the crosh terminal? Is there a magic key combo?

Sidenote: Couldn't create tags for crosh, chromeos

Note that I am not using the machine in developer mode.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in developer mode, you can open a shell and kill the ssh process.

```
kill `ps -u chronos | grep ssh | cut --characters=1-6`
```

(Assuming you only have 1 ssh session open)

This is nicer than closing the window if you're using panelize and want to keep a shell panel open.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Chrome OS does use OpenSSH:  [Chrome OS git /openssh](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=openssh.git;a=summary)

- Here's a [description of the escape characters](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1#ESCAPE+CHARACTERS)
- Here's a [blog post describing use](http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2006/01/24/ssh-escape-characters/)

I think the Chrome OS ssh config file path is `~/ssh/.config`

Comment: Damn, it looks like they disabled this option of OpenSSH by putting `-e none` in the crosh binary: http://codereview.chromium.org/5183004/

Answer (score 3):

The real answer: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

This is the hotkey to close a window, generally, and it is the official workaround for this issue.

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=10023#c17

Answer (score -1):

At the time that I wrote this answer, this was the answer. It has since been rectified.

I think the official answer is sadly to log out and then log back in. It works every time!!! Another method that I use is to just ignore it and open another terminal until ssh finally realizes that it is hosed and will go back to the ssh prompt.